# How to cycle through parameters to see quick info of each one in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In this situation, is there a way to see **namespaces** info without the need of having to type two commas?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't tell you that information if you just hover over `Serialize` and the click through the allowable overloads and get to the 1 that has the namspaces parameter?

Comment: No it doesn't. The first parameter it shows info is about **stream**, then after I put first comma it shows info about parameter **o**, and after second comma it shows info about **namespaces**. Now, my question is how can I get straight to **namespaces** info via maybe key shortcuts?

Comment: Was my answer able to assist you?

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a **keyboard shortcut** for what you are trying to accomplish.

In order to see all of the overloaded method parameters, you can place your cursor inside the method's parenthesis and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and that will bring up the first method, and then you can `arrow` up and down to go through all of the different types of overloaded methods.

So in your example:

```
using(Stream fileStream = new FileStream(imeXmlFajla,FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    xmlFormat.Serialize() // place cursor in between parenthesis and press Ctrl+Shift+Space
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is standard stuff. But I'm looking for info about parameter in method definition, or constructor, or whatever. Let me explain by sequence of steps. You have typed **MethodName(** inside VS and he offers overloaded methods. Now you go through them via up and down arrow key, and you find one that you think you may need. Now you know what first two parameters of her are but what is that third one? You don't know what it does so you can type **,,** to get the info about him shown in the same hover info box. Now I'm asking is there a better way than using commas?

Comment: @ThrashAbaddon I see what you mean.  Unfortunately there is nothing in VS that will work besides what you are currently doing.  There isn't any specific type of Intellisense customization like that.